# JAXB | Parsing xml file |Java class structure for a xml file - NullPointerException

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, java-8, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am new to jaxb, hence not able to understand what would be the class structure for the below xml file.
I want to read this xml file and put its contents in a java object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<CBML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sisostds.org/schemas/c-bml/1.0">
  -<Report>
    -<Context xsi:type="OtherContext">
       <OID>0</OID>
       <NameText/>
       <CategoryCode>ABC</CategoryCode>
     </Context>
    -<Report xsi:type="WhoLocationType">
      -<ReporterWho>
        -<OrganisationRef xsi:type="UnitRef">
           <OID>1234</OID>
         </OrganisationRef>
       </ReporterWho>
      -<ReportedWhen xsi:type="ReportedWhenType">
         <ReportingDatetime>20170711142654.882</ReportingDatetime>
       </ReportedWhen>
      -<ReportingData>
         <OID>9854</OID>
         <ReportingDataCategoryCode>XXXX</ReportingDataCategoryCode>
         <CredibilityCode>QWERTY</CredibilityCode>
       </ReportingData>
      -<WhoRef>
        -<ObjectItemRef xsi:type="UnitRef">
           <OID>7854</OID>
         </ObjectItemRef>
       </WhoRef>
      -<Location xsi:type="GeographicPoint">
         <OID>0</OID>
         <LatitudeCoordinate>50.6198949</LatitudeCoordinate>
         <LongitudeCoordinate>7.0869865</LongitudeCoordinate>
       </Location>
      -<ObjectItemLocation>
         <OID>0</OID>
         <BearingAngle/>
       </ObjectItemLocation>
     </Report>
   </Report>
 </CBML>
```

For the above xml i created below class structure.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CBML", namespace = "http://www.sisostds.org/schemas/c-bml/1.0")
public class CBML {
    //I have doubt here, as should it be called reporthead?
    //There is no element as reporthead in xml. But then what should it be?
    private ReportHead reportHead;
    ..getters/setters
}

public class ReportHead {

    private Context context;
    private Report report;
    ..getters/setters
}

public class Context {

    private String oid;
    private String nameText;
    private String categoryCode;
    ..getters/setters
}

public class Report {

    private ReporterWho reporterWho;
    private ReportedWhen reportedWhen;
    private ReportingData reportingData;
    private WhoRef whoRef;
    private Location location;
    private ObjectItemLocation objectItemLocation;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class ReporterWho {

    private OrganisationRef organisationRef;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class OrganisationRef {

    private String oid;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class ReportedWhen {

    private String reportingDateTime;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class ReportingData {

    private String oid;
    private String reportingDataCategoryCode;
    private String credibilityCode;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class WhoRef {

    private ObjectItemRef objectItemRef;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class ObjectItemRef {

    private String oid;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class Location {

    private String oid;
    private String latitudeCoordinate;
    private String longitudeCoordinate;
    ..getters/setters
}
public class ObjectItemLocation {

    private String oid;
    private String bearingAngle;
    ..getters/setters
}
```

The code for parsing the xml into java object is

```
try {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CBML.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                CBML cbml = (CBML) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

                System.out.println(cbml.getReportHead().getContext().getCategoryCode());
            } catch(JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Please can someone suggest. I am not able to understand why it is not able to parse the xml document.
Thanks.

Comment: The `<Report>` element (immediately below the `<CBML ...>`) in your XML
doesn't match your `private ReportHead` reportHead;` in your `CBML` class. May be it should be `<ReportHead>` instead.

Comment: I cannot change the xml structure. Therefore <Report> cannot be changed to <ReportHead>.
I was thinking on the same line that instead of ReportHead i should have Report in java class, but then if you see the xml, Report again has Report inside it. <Report xsi:type="WhoLocationType">
How should i do it in java?

Comment: May be adding the annotation `@XmlElement(name="Report")` before `private ReportHead reportHead;` will do the trick.

Comment: It gives me the error
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "reportHead"
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at public de.fraunhofer.bml.model.ReportHead de.fraunhofer.bml.model.CBML.getReportHead()
  at de.fraunhofer.bml.model.CBML
 
this problem is related to the following location:
  at private de.fraunhofer.bml.model.ReportHead de.fraunhofer.bml.model.CBML.reportHead
  at de.fraunhofer.bml.model.CBML

Comment: Then add the annotation `@XmlElement(name="Report")`
not before `private ReportHead reportHead;`,
but before `public ReportHead getReportHead()`.

Comment: It still gives the same error that i initially got i.e. java.lang.NullPointerException

Also what is the difference in adding it over getter method instead of variable?

Comment: I recommend, sooner or later to work through a JAXB tutorial. You can start with [Oracle's Introduction of JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) or any other.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts.